# Calculating if $n!$ is divisible by $i$ using Legendre's Formula (previously asked about $y=y∗a\pmod i$)

Tags: factorial

I have a task in which I need to prove whether $n!$ is divisible by any integer $i$.

I already know that if $n!$ can be divided by $i$, then $n+1!$ can also be divided by $i$, so I really only need to find the lowest factorial divisible by i.

Also, evaluations such as "is $5!$ divisible by $4$?" are easy.
$5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1$ The fact that $4$ is a factor clearly means that $5!$ is divisible by $4$.

The problem comes when finding if $n!$ is divisible by an $i$ bigger than $n$.

For example, where $n = 21$ and $i = 560$.

The problem I've got specifies that I must be able to test values up to $2^{32}$ which is $4,294,967,296$.

This task is for a computer programming class. The point of the task was to get around the memory space issue raised by big numbers, and $4294967296!$ *is* a pretty big number (at least in terms of bits of data). Most computers will run out of space unless you import some special tools. My task was to work this out without using special tools.

I delved into the internet and found this:

$y = y * a \pmod i$

Start with $y = 1$ and increase $a$ by $1$ each time you perform the calculation.  Example:

$y * a \pmod {560} = y$

$1 * 1 \pmod {560} \equiv 1$
$1 * 2 \pmod {560} \equiv 2$
$2 * 3 \pmod {560} \equiv 6$
$6 * 4 \pmod {560} \equiv 24$
$24 * 5 \pmod {560} \equiv 120$
$120 * 6 \pmod {560} \equiv 160$
$160 * 7 \pmod {560} \equiv 0$

If $y \equiv 0$ and $a$ is less than or equal to $n$, we know that $a!$ is divisible by $i$.
If $a$ goes above $n$ without $y$ ever reaching $0$, then we know that $n!$ is not divisible by $i$.

Indeed, $7! = 5040$ and $5040 / 560 = 9$

I should probably apologise:
I'm not from a mathematical background, so I struggle to read equations / formulas / proofs beyond the very basic. This either means I may have already used wrong symbols etc. or that I may not understand a particularly technical answer.

The last two hours I've spent googling don't tell me much except that this *does* work, rather than *why* or *how*.

The significance of this formula appears to be in taking the modulus of a previous operation and using that for the new operation, but why the modulus? Why exactly does that number allow us to always reach a conclusion?

---

EDIT

---

I have seen a post or two regarding Legendre's formula (also known as de Polignac's formula) suggesting this is a more efficient way for dealing with my problem.

I understand the workings, but am not sure how I use it?
For example, when finding out if 10,000 will divide 20!...?

According to Legendre's Formula I do the following:
$\nu_2 (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{2^1}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{20}{2^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{20}{2^3}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{20}{2^4}\rfloor = 18$
$\nu_3 (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{3^1}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{20}{3^2}\rfloor = 8$
$\nu_5 (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{5^1}\rfloor = 4$
$\nu_7 (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{7^1}\rfloor = 2$
$\nu_9 (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{9^1}\rfloor = 2$
$\nu_{11} (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{11^1}\rfloor = 1$
$\nu_{13} (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{13^1}\rfloor = 1$
$\nu_{17} (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{17^1}\rfloor = 1$
$\nu_{19} (20!) = \lfloor\frac{20}{19^1}\rfloor = 1$
Which then leaves us with:
$ 20! = 2^{18} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 9^2 \cdot 11^1 \cdot 13^1 \cdot 17^1 \cdot 19^1$

How do I get from here to deciding that 20! is divisible by 10,000?...

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351177/prove-or-derive-the-de-polignac-formula-for-the-prime-decomposition-of-n).

Comment: Very interesting, but I can't *quite* work out how it relates to the formula I'm using. It has enabled me to see that (actually) my solution will always return a prime factorial, so I see why you linked to that information, but it hasn't helped me understand the formula I've got.

Comment: It's not really related to that formula. It's for a different (and typically far more efficient) way of checking whether $i$ divides $n!$. Find the prime factorisation of $i$, and use the formula to check whether each prime dividing $i$ occurs in the factorisation of $n!$ sufficiently often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but why the modulus?

The short answer is: because the modulus tells us whether one number divides another.

Some elaboration on that cannot hurt, of course. So let us elaborate. The notation

$$a \equiv b \pmod{c},$$

where $a,b,c$ are integers, by definition means that $c$ divides $a-b$, i.e. there is an integer $k$ such that $a-b = k\cdot c$. Hence $c$ divides $a$ if and only if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{c}$, and to see whether $i$ divides $n!$, we must check whether $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{i}$. The thing that makes this feasible for large $n$ (and $i > n$, it's trivially true for $i \leqslant n$) is that we do not need to compute $n!$ to see what remainder that would leave when divided by $i$. The property that allows this is that for all integers $m$ we have the implication

$$\bigl(a \equiv b \pmod{c}\bigr) \implies \bigl( ma \equiv mb \pmod{c}\bigr).\tag{$\ast$}$$

This is easy to see: since $a\equiv b \pmod{c}$ means $a-b = k\cdot c$ for some integer $k$, it follows that $ma - mb = m(a-b) = mk\cdot c$ for that same $k$, and $mk$ is of course an integer. So $c$ divides $ma - mb$, i.e. $ma \equiv mb \pmod{c}$.

And your algorithm is just applying $(\ast)$ at each step in the calculation of the factorial. Inductively, if $k! \equiv r_k \pmod{i}$, then by $(\ast)$ we have

$$(k+1)! = (k+1)\cdot k! \equiv (k+1)\cdot r_k \pmod{i}.$$

And then $r_{k+1}$ is the remainder of $(k+1)\cdot r_k$ upon division by $i$.

And clearly, if $r_k = 0$, then $r_{k+1} = 0$ too, so if we ever have a remainder of $0$ before reaching $n$, then we also have $r_n = 0$, i.e. $i$ divides $n!$.

---

Reducing modulo $i$ at each step solves the space problem, since none of the intermediate results is larger than $i^2$. But it's not the most efficient algorithm, since it typically requires $O(n)$ multiplications and divisions (reductions modulo $i$). It is more efficient to find the prime factorisation of $i$ (in the range up to $2^{32}$ that is still efficiently done by trial division), and then check whether each prime dividing $i$ occurs with a high enough exponent in the prime factorisation of $n!$. The exponent of a prime $p$ in the factorisation of $n!$ is quickly found using de Polignac's formula.

Comment: When I "check whether each prime dividing i occurs with a high enough exponent", what counts as a high enough exponent? 
I have updated my question with information about Legendre's Formula (de Polignac's Formula).

Comment: @Matthew You need $\nu_p(n!) \geqslant \nu_p(i)$ for all primes. If $p$ doesn't divide $i$, then $\nu_p(i) = 0$ and it's trivially satisfied. So we need only compute $\nu_p(n!)$ for primes dividing $i$. In your example with $i = 10000$, we have $i = 2^4\cdot 5^4$, so we must check whether $\nu_2(20!) \geqslant \nu_2(2^4\cdot 5^4) = 4$ and $\nu_5(20!) \geqslant \nu_5(2^4\cdot 5^4) = 4$. Both are true, so $20!$ is divisible by $10000$.

Comment: Correct. The smallest factorial divisible by $10^5$ is $25!$. and that is even divisible by $10^6$. Note that as a rule of thumb, if $n!$ is not divisible by $i$, that usually fails due to the large primes dividing $i$ not having a high enough exponent in $n!$ [the exception is when $n$ is very small, or $i$ is divisible by a high power of a small prime], so it tends to be marginally faster to check the larger primes dividing $i$ first.

Comment: Okay awesome, I think I've got it. So, this means if $i=100,000$ rather than $10,000$ (but keeping $n=20$), we have: $i=2^5 \cdot 5^5$. This means $\nu_2(20!) = 18$ which is greater than $\nu_2(2^5 \cdot 5^5) = 5$. Great so far, however, $\nu_5(20!) = 4$ is less than $\nu5(2^5 \cdot 5^5) = 5$ meaning $100,000$ does NOT divide $20!$. This is awesome! Although I clearly don't have the same knowledge as you guys, this is really interesting! Thank you.
Sorry this comment got re-posted AFTER you replied to it. For some reason it didn't let me edit so I had no option but to copy and paste.

Comment: Ah, right, okay. So, once I've calculated all prime factors of $i$, I should then work DOWN this list for the prime factors of $n!$? This is really interesting. Starting to wish I'd paid more attention in school and gone on to do a maths degree rather than computer science. Or a combo...

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference whether you start at the largest prime factor of $i$ and go down, or at the smallest and go up. Compared to finding the factorisation of $i$, all these checks combined are - except for cases where $i$ has only few and small prime factors where the factorisation is unusually cheap - fairly insignificant. And even when factorising $i$ is cheap, the checks are still also cheap. But if you're counting cycles, starting at the largest prime factor and then working down is on average a bit faster, since you more often hit an early exit.

Comment: If for example $i$ has a prime factor larger than $n$, you know immediately that $i$ cannot divide $n!$, without looking whether $\nu_2(n!) \geqslant \nu_2(i)$. But that only matters if you do the test really often and need to squeeze out every bit of performance you can.

Comment: Would just like to add that, I have now implemented your suggested method in C++. It does work, but for big primes (near 2^31) like 2147483647 it takes significantly longer than the method I used above... I mean I've been sitting here for ten minutes watching it compute, the method I originally offered reliably takes 45 seconds or less.
For small numbers your method is significantly faster. Just doesn't appear to scale well...

Comment: @Matthew That sounds like you have integer overflow issues. To avoid such issues, compute $\nu_p(n!)$ with `exponent = 0; m = n; do { m /= p; exponent += m; } while(m > 0);`, not with computing the powers of the prime. It might be something else, though, I can't be sure without seeing the code.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.
Finding the factors of $i$ is the thing that takes the most time. I'm generating primes rather than looking them up using a list. It's an algorithm's class, we've been instructed to generate our own information rather than use a predefined list. Generating primes (and then testing them against $i$) takes ages.
I didn't mean any offence. Your version is a very elegant way to do it, but is either going to take a very long time to compute, or will take even longer to make it efficient with my available implementation methods.

Comment: What magnitude can $i$ have? Factorisation is a hard problem for large numbers, but for small (32-bit, in some sense also 64-bit) numbers trial division is fast enough. You only need to check up to $\sqrt{i}$ in the worst case. In this problem, you can stop at $n$ (that is, stop at $\min \{n, \sqrt{i}\}$), since if $i$ isn't completely factorised with primes $\leqslant n$, it has at least one prime factor $> n$ and hence cannot divide $n!$. If your $i$ is 32 bits, then generating the needed primes via sieving is a matter of milliseconds. If 64 bits (unsigned), you might need primes up to

Comment: $2^{32}$, which takes a couple of seconds to sieve (and requires a non-negligible amount of storage space). It can then make sense to sieve only primes to say one million, and after that, if needed, switch to trial division using also composite numbers. But the best strategy depends on the typical/average sizes of $i$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$i,n$ has some prime factorizations. $p_1^a\cdot p_2^b\cdot p_3^c$, and $p_1^r\cdot p_2^s\cdot p_3^t$ respectively.

$i|n!$ if $a\le r,$ and $b\le s$, and $c\le t$

How to find $r,s,t$

if $n<p$ then $p$ does not divide $n!$

if $n>p$ then it does.

if $k< p \implies p^k| (kp)!$

but if $k>p$ we can divide one more $p$ out of $(kp)!$ because $p$ divided each appearance with a factor of $p$ and it goes into $p^2$ twice.

$r = \lfloor \frac {n}{p} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac {n}{p^2} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac {n}{p^3} \rfloor \cdots$

Comment: What is $k$ / where did it come from?

Comment: $k$ is just a constant.